# Widget parent not immediately available in KV file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a rule in my KV file for a class that we'll call Foo that inherits from the Widget class, which I create  instances of in my python file: (most irrelevant details have been removed)

In python:

```
Class Foo(Widget):
    x_coord = NumericProperty()
    y_coord = NumericProperty()
```

In Kv:

```
<Foo>:
    pos: self.x_coord + self.parent.bar, self.y_coord() + self.parent.barbar
```

However when I instantiate the class:

```
new_foo = Foo()
new_foo.x_coord = 7
new_foo.y_coord = 10
[do some more stuff with it]

<a parent widget>.add_widget(new_foo)
```

I get an error saying `type object NoneType has no attribute bar`

It seems to me that the KV file tries to apply the rule as soon as the class is instantiated, but it hasn't got a parent yet because it hasn't been added to anything. I even tried adding a temporary subclass called parent to Foo which had working values for all the properties i referenced, and this did stop the error, but I immediately got a new one as kivy couldn't overwrite the temporary class to add the actual parent.

How do I get around this? Is there a way of passing the parent as an argument? Or should I write out the rule in python instead and put it in an init for the Foo class?

Comment: You can do something like `(self.parent.barbar if self.parent is not None else 0)`.

Comment: You can also use Clock.schedule in _init_, schedule an after_init method to do whatever needs to be done after instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parent` is a property too. That means you can create `on_parent` method to be called when its set to use it properties:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Parent(FloatLayout):
    bar = NumericProperty(20)


class Child(Button):
    def on_parent(self, obj, parent):
        self.pos = (parent.bar, parent.bar)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Parent()
        child = Child(text="Test", size_hint=(None, None))
        parent.add_widget(child)
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If you want to react when parent property is changed you can bind a method to parent's property in `on_parent` method:

```
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Parent(FloatLayout):
    bar = NumericProperty(20)


class Child(Button):
    def on_parent(self, obj, parent):
        self.pos = (parent.bar, parent.bar)
        parent.bind(bar=self.update_pos)

    def update_pos(self, obj, bar):
        self.pos = (bar, bar)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Parent()
        child = Child(text="Test", size_hint=(None, None))
        parent.add_widget(child)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.change_parent_bar, parent), 3)
        return parent

    def change_parent_bar(self, parent, dt):
        parent.bar = 50


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```